# DOSBox autoexec menu design

Tags: batch-file, dos, dosbox, autoexec

I'm trying to make a (somewhat) stylish DOS menu as a present for my father.

I was able to get the whole menu system to work, but I wanted to gussy it up with some box drawing characters and, possibly, colored text.

In [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjaXhKp3BeE), the user shows an example of what I'm trying to do (example at the 5:00 mark), but doesn't explain how those characters are being rendered. In the Notepad document, it is displayed as goofy characters.

Do I need to save the file with a special type of encoding? Can it only be done in Notepad (I'm using TextEdit on Mac)? Can someone provide an example menu that can be added to DOSBox's [autoexec] config?

Also, I'm not sure if it is possible, but how can the text color/background color be changed? When running DOSBox initially, it shows their welcome screen with a blue background and box drawing characters, so I would think all of that is possible.

I tried using escaped unicode characters and I tried using a capital-E acute (as shown in the linked video), but they just render funky stuff when run in DOSBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrepancy in characters is a result of different [code pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) being used in character rendering. English-speaking Windows uses ANSI code page 1252 (otherwise known as [Latin-1](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-codes.php)), while DOS uses OEM code page 437, or [IBM-PC](http://www.ascii-codes.com/).

The codepage that Windows uses will vary based on your [system language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Windows_.28ANSI.29_code_pages), so you many need to experiment to find the correct characters, but basically, find the character you want to print in 437 (say ╔, which is 200) and then in your code use the 1252 version (where 200 is È). Then save the file in ANSI encoding.

Comment: You can use the Terminal font in Notepad, as it has the "OEM/DOS" encoding you need.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Interestingly, TextEdit does not have an option to "save as" in ANSI, but I was able to do the work in Notepad using the proper Latin-1 character reference, save in ANSI, then copy it to my Mac where DOSBox is running.